# How do you us Windows + t in remote desktop?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, taskbar

How do you use <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> in remote desktop?

I want to focus on my taskbar so that I can switch through apps from my taskbar. I want to still apply the windows combination on my local computer.

I know the functions <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Page</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> is similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> is similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd>.

I want to use <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> because it will allow me to focus on individual monitors while switching.

Comment: There isn't a remote desktop equivalent to windows+t. See [Remote Desktop Services Shortcut Keys - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-shortcut-keys)

Comment: Windows T works for me through Microsoft Remote Desktop. Just tested it and i'm able to cycle through all the apps on the taskbar. Must be a setting somewhere.